# How to use one class to horizontally center any element?

Tags: html, css

I want to define a class such that to which ever element I apply that class that element gets horizontally centred in its parent container.

The class can be applied to `img` , `iframes` or `divs` each of which could be of different size.

Is it possible to have such one class for all of them?

And how can achieve this probably the solution would require setting right, left margins automatically equal to each other and according to the size of the elements and left over space? But how that can be achieved.

Closest I have been able to reach is this but it doesn't work:

```
.centreThis{
margin: 0 auto;
max-height: 964px;
max-width: 680px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 10px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Would `margin: 0 auto` work?

Comment: tried doesn't work, also updated my question with a snippet.

Comment: Easy: don’t. Give your elements classes that describe how they’re used, not what they should look like, and write selectors tailored to each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of CSS rules to address various elements:

```
.center {
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

This will center align `p`, `img`, `div` and `iframe` elements, and others. Here's the full **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/8G7Dm/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `centered` class:

```
.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Work for:

- `<div>` tag;
- `img` tag
- `iframe` tag

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QbRa7/1/)

**EDIT:** if you put some text right inside `<div>` with that tag, `the text will not center`, cause you don't have setted `text-align: center` property.

**HOW CAN I CENTER TEXT INSIDE CENTERED DIV?**
Simple, just add a `<p>` element inside that div and CSS:

```
.centered p {text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `text-align: center;` on a container element and `display: inline-block;` on a child element that you want to center.

Also, note that the `margin: 0 auto;` method only works when you have a defined `width`.